# query varchar field with date values

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar

on sql-server db i need to query the dates > getdate from a varchar field

My table is like below ( `activatioDate` type is `varchar(100)`) :

```
id | activatioDate  
22 | 12/3/2021     
23 | 12/7/2019     
24 | 12/9/2020    
25 | 12/3/2019     
26 | 12/11/2019    
27 | 12/1/2024
```

my query

```
select * from mytable
where activatioDate > GETDATE()
```

Expected result

```
22 | 12/3/2021     
24 | 12/9/2020     
27 | 12/1/2024
```

I've got the following error 
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. "

Any suggestion?

Comment: Dates aren't strings, they are binary values. Don't store dates into string fields. That's a very serious bug. Use the correct type, `date`. Anything else just covers up the bug. This particular string format doesn't permit ordering and range queries. `12/3/1800` will always come *after* `11/12/2021`

Comment: Be careful of saving date values as string - instead use datetimes as these are universal whereas string-values requires convert and you might mess up the DMY order down the road if you want to change language or DATEFORMAT in your database. Datetimes are not affected by these changes, whereas string-values are affected by these settings. Therefore datetimes are much more robust.

Answer (score 2):

You **need** to fix your design; that's the real problem here. Firstly, change the values to a unambiguous date/time format:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET activatioDate  = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,activatioDate,101),120);
```

Then you can `ALTER` the table:

```
ALTER dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN activatioDate  date;
```

And then, finally, your query will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE activatioDate > GETDATE();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, activatioDate, 101) > GETDATE();
```

But in general you should avoid storing your dates as text in your SQL database.

Comment: Apart from that, these kind of queries will lead to exponentially rising query times for large data sets. The entire column needs to be converted to Datetime before the expression can be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Find all employees who didn't make any orders in the past 6 months. Tricky thing - the date field is varchar. You need to cast it to Date and apply Date functions